# Override Sealed is valid but why not Virtual Sealed in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

The below code snippet is valid

```
public class BaseClass
{

   public virtual void Display()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Virtual method");
   }
 }

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{

  public override sealed void Display()
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Sealed method");
  }
```

}

But why not

```
public class BaseClass
{

 public virtual sealed void Display()
 {
          Console.WriteLine("Virtual method");
 }
}
```

**Edited**

Actually I was reading [What is sealed class and sealed method?](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/what-are-sealed-classes-and-sealed-methods/) this article. So I was following the author's instruction. Suddenly I tried to play the concept of Sealed with the base class. That's why I came up with this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`override sealed` is valid because it says "I'm overriding a base class method, but derived classes can't override me." That makes sense. One part of it is talking about the relationship to its base class; the other is talking about the relationship to derived classes.

`virtual sealed` would be saying "You can override me (`virtual`) but you can't override me (`sealed`)." That makes no sense. The two modifiers are contradictory *and* apply to the same relationship.

Answer (score 4):

Sealed:

> You can also use the sealed modifier on a method or property that
>   overrides a virtual method or property in a base class. This enables
>   you to allow classes to derive from your class and prevent them from
>   overriding specific virtual methods or properties.

Override:

> The override modifier is required to extend or modify the abstract or
>   virtual implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or
>   event.

`Sealed` means it is the "end-of-the-hierarchy" for the given method/class. Making a method `virtual` is merely saying *"this is the default behavior, **override me** if you want different behavior"* and `sealed` which means *"this cannot be overridden ever"* is a paradox.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you'd expect that to even do.

The [`sealed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/88c54tsw(v=vs.100).aspx) keyword means you can't inherit it.

> You can also use the sealed modifier on a method or property that overrides a virtual method or property in a base class. This enables you to allow classes to derive from your class and prevent them from overriding specific virtual methods or properties.

The [`virtual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) keyword means you can.

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived class. For example, this method can be overridden by any class that inherits it:

I'm not sure why you'd need or want both.

When applying it to `override`, that makes sense. That means "you can't override this behavior," and effectively overrules the previous (relative to the hierarchy) `virtual` keyword on the method or property.

Comment: It's not clear why you've quoted the section of documentation about how `sealed` applied to a *class* when the OP is applying it to a *method*. It would be clearer if you'd edit the answer to include the more relevant section instead: "You can also use the sealed modifier on a method or property that overrides a virtual method or property in a base class. This enables you to allow classes to derive from your class and prevent them from overriding specific virtual methods or properties."

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, fair enough. Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed.